# Permission Denied error when using Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

Below is my code snippet:

```
   string ApplPath = Server.MapPath("./");
    switch (ddlReportType.Text)
    {
        case "District-wise":
            if (ddlDistrict.Text == "All")
                Response.Redirect(ApplPath + "contentReportAllDistricts.aspx");
            else if (ddlDistrict.Text != "All" && ddlDistrict.Text != "-- Select --")
                Response.Redirect(ApplPath + "contentReportSelectedBlocks.aspx?" + ddlDistrict.Text);
            break;
     }
```

When I was not using `Server.MapPath`, the application was running well, but now, IE debugger displays error: `Permisson Denied`.

I am working on a local host and running the application from local host itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.MapPath will return the physical path to your site (e.g. C:/MySite/...), you should change your code as follows, to get the path from the root:

```
switch (ddlReportType.Text) 
    { 
        case "District-wise": 
            if (ddlDistrict.Text == "All") 
                Response.Redirect("~/contentReportAllDistricts.aspx"); 
            else if (ddlDistrict.Text != "All" && ddlDistrict.Text != "-- Select --") 
                Response.Redirect( "~/contentReportSelectedBlocks.aspx?" + ddlDistrict.Text); 
            break; 
     }
```

The ~ symbol will resolve to the root of your site.

Comment: I have a folder in my root app. path. This page is in the folder. When I used your suggestion, it displays error: Resource not found. It is obvious that I should append the folder name in the path like: "~/myFolder/contentReportAllDistricts.aspx", but is there any way to get entire path of the running page?

Comment: @RPK - You can use Request.PhysicalPath

Comment: @AVD It works, but it is also picking running page name. I just want the path till the current folder name. Is there any way to discard the page name it is picking?

Comment: You can use Request.Path method (there are number of Path related methods with Request object.)

Comment: @RPK You can use relative path:  Response.redirect"../contentRportAllDistricts.aspx"